# Best way to create an account system in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I am trying to create a system like LinkedIn but a simplified one. I tried doing so, but I came to realization that it will not be possible until I create something like an account system because at the moment the user will login - ok but then what? How is he going to be able to upload CV under his name. I haven't totally understood how it should work and as you can already probably tell I am not very experienced. ;p

So my question here is: How can create a system where the user will register and enter personal details, work experience and upload CV? Employers will have to register as employers and search employees with being able to filter them by keywords such as "good with computers". At the same time, be able to view their profile.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: all things start with coding and or trying something, can you show us what you have attempted.. I am voting to close this because it's too broad in nature

Comment: Well, I have created mysql functions for adding a user and deleting a user.

Comment: that's good to know.. once again how does that help anyone in regards to your question when we can't see what it is you have done code wise. you will need more than just sql do some `MVC tutorial` google searching.. good luck

Comment: I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.  It sounds like you have an idea for something, but want us to make it for you.  Down vote and flagging for removal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard ASP.NET MVC application template in VS already contains working skeleton of login and profile infrastructure, including two factor authentication, external authentication support and stubs for email and sms services.

Comment: Just try to create new ASP.NET MVC project in VS.